# Laser on a Train Question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, visible-light, relative-motion

The two trains below are traveling at 1/2c. Each train has two identical pulsating lasers. One laser is pointed directly ahead of the train the other is pointed at 90 degrees to the direction of motion. Which drawing is correct, as seen from the train? This is not a homework question. The concept behind the question is: Light leaving the train in the direction of motion is not affected by the train's motion, but what about the light perpendicular to the train's motion. Is it also independent of the train's motion?
[image]

Comment: Whether or not a question is *actual* homework or not is irrelevant by our current policies - you are asking an exercise-type question with no effort shown and no conceptual question asked.

Comment: I drew the picture. That takes some effort.

Comment: I made changes to the question. Please reconsider the "on Hold" Thanks.

Comment: The question is quite clear.

Comment: The [relativistic velocity-addition formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula) is easy to find even for general velocities (though not necessarily trivial to apply). What *exactly* is your problem with applying it in this case?

Comment: I am not a physic student. I think it's a good question that many readers could relate to, but It's your call. If you think it's a bad question then it wont be on the forum.  I can live with that.

Comment: The correct one is A